# Custom Log File That Doesn't Grow Past a Given Size

Tags: python

I need to write some output to a log file every time certain events in my application are triggered. Right now I'm doing this in the simplest way imagineable:

```
with open('file.log', 'a+') as file:
    file.write('some info')
```

This works, but the problem is I don't want the file to grow indefinitely. I want a hard size cutoff of, say 25 MB. But I don't want to simply clear the file when it reaches that size.

Instead, I want it to function how I believe other log files work, clearing the oldest data from the top of the file and appending the new data to the end of the file. What would be a good approach to achieving this in Python? Note that I can't use Python's logging library because this is for a Celery application and (a) I already have logging set up for purposes unrelated to this and (b) Celery and the logging library do not play well together AT ALL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import os
statinfo = os.stat('somefile.txt')
```

This will return the size of somefile.txt in bytes.
Then you can do something like:

```
if statinfo.st_size > 25000000:
```

You can implement this however you want. You could read up to the number of lines that are going to be replaced, delete those and then save the reminder in a temporary file, then you could write the data you wish, and append the temporary file. This would not be very effective, but it would work.